# Launch an Activity on touching anywhere in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, event-handling

I'm new to android programming. I created an App with two Activities - the Main Activity and then another called New1.
Now this is what I need to do. I want the second Activity to be launched when the user touches anywhere on the Main Activity. I tried doing this by using onTouch(), but it doesn't work.
Following is the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.firstapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, New1.class);
      startActivity(intent);
        return true;    
    }
}
```

And the following is the activity_main.xml layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="206dp"
        android:text="Touch Anywhere" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm working with eclipse and using Android 4.0 as target. Please help!

Comment: Try setting the touch listener for the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="206dp"
    android:text="Touch Anywhere" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then set `RelativeLayout` on louch listener in `onCreate` i.e.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this override method
This method called if user interacts with the screen.

```
 public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
   // Call your intent here.
   };
```

You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

A listener will work when you attach that listener to something. As i can see you have implemented onTouchListener but haven't attach that listener to anything.Get a reference to your relativelayout by findViewById or get the decoreview for your activity and attach your listener to that view.
For example:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id. some id);
rl.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `android:id="@+id/myParentLayout"` to your xml layout parent item and then using OnTouchListener on that view. You can read about OnTouchListener at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html This should get the job done.

```
.....
// In onCreate for Activity
  // Find your view , ex: if your parent is a LinearLayout
  LinearLayout mParentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myParentLayout);
  myParentLayout.setOnTouchListener(ParentTouchListener);


 } // end onCreate()

 OnTouchListener ParentTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

         // Handle Actions if user presses down on screen
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

           // Do something

           // Action supported, screen was touched
           return true;
        }

         // default return when touch action is unsupported
         return false;
      }
 };
```

Also , the MotionEvent Actions are at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: Thats right! And and so were Saif and Mukesh above... Thank you for your time